# How to find PHP filename and ID of the URL?

Tags: php, kali-linux, url-redirection, web, htaccess

.htaccess is now a very common URL rewrite to make it SEO friendly and cover the database IDs.

What are the ways to explore php file on the server given to URL via .htaccess?

**Example** : 
The URL is `www.domain.com/news/56`.

I expect to find `news.php?id=56` i.e. `www.domain.com/news.php?id=56`

Answer (score 1):

#### No, there is no way for you to find this.

The reason for this is that rewrite rules are not visible to the client, as they are performed server-side. You further cannot be sure whether or not it is a simple rewrite, or if the whole HTTP request is handed over to a complex web application, which parses the route to determine which class and method sends the response.

Comment: Although most are asking for help with their "`.htaccess` problems" on SE, making their rewrite rules all publicly available. ;)

Comment: Precisely, Esa. I am aware that the .htaccess is performed at the server-side but I am here to explore options, not to read .htaccess clean but figure it out how to reach the PHP file. Maybe a script to check?

Comment: @EsaJokinen do .htaccess files still see widespread use?

Comment: @multithr3at3d: There are two possibilities: either they are still mainly used despite it's clearly not recommended by the [`.htaccess` documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html)  itself... or anyone who has grown out of `.htaccess` won't keep asking any questions as they already know what they are doing. (Or, in worst case scenario, most of the administrators have no clue what they are doing.)